# Encrypting in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a VBScript script which I would like to run in ASP.NET, is there anyone who can help on rewriting this function in ASP.NET , C# , so that it returns the same algorithm of encryption?  This was an ASP.NET Encryption function, converted for Classic ASP usage, but I need to get it working on the ASP.NET code.. How would this code look like in ASP.NET considering its using an ASP.NET Encryption method?

```
Public Function EncryptAES(ByVal sIn As String, ByVal sKey As String) As String
    Dim AES As New RijndaelManaged
    Dim ahashMD5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    AES.Key = ahashMD5.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey))
    AES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
    Dim AESEncrypt As ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateEncryptor()
    Dim aBuffer As Byte() = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sIn)
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(AESEncrypt.TransformFinalBlock(aBuffer, 0, aBuffer.Length))
End Function

Public Function DecryptAES(ByVal sOut As String, ByVal sKey As String) As String
    Dim dAES As New RijndaelManaged
    Dim dahashMD5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    dAES.Key = dahashMD5.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey))
    dAES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
    Dim dAESDecrypt As ICryptoTransform = dAES.CreateDecryptor()
    sOut = Replace(sOut, " ", "+", 1, -1, CompareMethod.Text)
    Dim daBuffer As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(sOut)
    Return System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(dAESDecrypt.TransformFinalBlock(daBuffer, 0, daBuffer.Length))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a Classic ASP script

Man, this is pure .NET code. So converting .NET to .NET hardly makes sense.

If you want to convert this VB.NET code to C#, here's how it would look like:

```
public string EncryptAES(string sIn, string sKey)
{
    RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged();
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider ahashMD5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    AES.Key = ahashMD5.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey));
    AES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    ICryptoTransform AESEncrypt = AES.CreateEncryptor();
    byte[] aBuffer = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sIn);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(AESEncrypt.TransformFinalBlock(aBuffer, 0, aBuffer.Length));
}

public string DecryptAES(string sOut, string sKey)
{
    RijndaelManaged dAES = new RijndaelManaged();
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider dahashMD5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    dAES.Key = dahashMD5.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey));
    dAES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    ICryptoTransform dAESDecrypt = dAES.CreateDecryptor();
    sOut = sOut.Replace(" ", "+");
    byte[] daBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(sOut);
    return System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(dAESDecrypt.TransformFinalBlock(daBuffer, 0, daBuffer.Length));
}
```

Comment: It's actually VBScript, but it was made in a way that i can use it from my classic asp scripts.. So i just want to know how to use it in ASP.NET, since i dont know how to convert it to C#.

Comment: @Wilkins, you could do ASP.NET with VB.NET. Also you cannot use this code in classic ASP. It requires .NET framework. You don't need C# for ASP.NET. Or maybe you want to convert this code to C#?

Comment: the page is C#, this code is VBScript, so i dont think they can co-exist on the same page right?

Comment: @Wilkins, this code is NOT VBScript. It is VB.NET. There is a humongous difference between those 2 languages. And, no you cannot mix VB.NET and C# in the same ASP.NET page. I have provided you with a translation to C# of this code.

Comment: i plugged in that code in the ASP.NET all the way at the bottom, and i get this error:  CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

What would i do to not get this error?

Comment: @Wilkins, you need to place those 2 methods inside some existing class or create a new class. In fact I would recommend you start reading a C# tutorial before going further because the questions you ask indicate a total lack of knowledge of C#.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov *cough* of .Net in general

Comment: i put it in a class, but now i get this error: 'Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Strings' does not exist in the current context'

Comment: @Wilkins, I have updated my post and replaced the error line with `sOut = sOut.Replace(" ", "+");`. Try it.

Comment: Ok, no more error, but it is not encrypting.. i am calling the function like this..

string EncUSERID = EncryptAES(USERID,"123")  and it will not encrypt, just gives me normal string.

Comment: Do these functions have to go on top of the page or bottom of the page to work properly? in the .CS file?

Comment: @Wilkins, I have tested the `EncryptAES` function like this: `EncryptAES("some test", "123")` and it returned `sSsNBw0QMYlYlqTYu8aucA==`. The location of those functions doesn't have any matter on their output.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the [Telerik Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/).
Find below.

```
public string EncryptAES(string sIn, string sKey)
{
    RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged();
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider ahashMD5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    AES.Key = ahashMD5.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey));
    AES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    ICryptoTransform AESEncrypt = AES.CreateEncryptor();
    byte[] aBuffer = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sIn);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(AESEncrypt.TransformFinalBlock(aBuffer, 0, aBuffer.Length));
}

public string DecryptAES(string sOut, string sKey)
{
    RijndaelManaged dAES = new RijndaelManaged();
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider dahashMD5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    dAES.Key = dahashMD5.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey));
    dAES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    ICryptoTransform dAESDecrypt = dAES.CreateDecryptor();
    sOut = Strings.Replace(sOut, " ", "+", 1, -1, CompareMethod.Text);
    byte[] daBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(sOut);
    return System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(dAESDecrypt.TransformFinalBlock(daBuffer, 0, daBuffer.Length));
}
```

Comment: I get this error: 'Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Strings' does not exist in the current context' in Decrypt function

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) to convert your VB.Net code to C#.

As @Darin Dimitrov pointed out this is definitely VB.Net which is definitely NOT VBScript/VB6/ASP Classic

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately conversion tools don't fix problems with code. All those disposable objects are giving me panic attacks.

```
public string EncryptAES(string sIn, string sKey)
{
    using (var secure = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        using (var ahashMd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            secure.Key = ahashMd5.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey));
            secure.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            using (ICryptoTransform aesEncrypt = secure.CreateEncryptor())
            {
                byte[] aBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sIn);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(
                          aesEncrypt.TransformFinalBlock(
                              aBuffer, 0, aBuffer.Length));
            }
        }
    }
}

public string DecryptAES(string sOut, string sKey)
{
    using (var secure = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        using (var dahashMd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            secure.Key = dahashMd5.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey));
            secure.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            using (ICryptoTransform dAesDecrypt = secure.CreateDecryptor())
            {
                sOut = sOut.Replace(" ", "+");
                byte[] daBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(sOut);
                return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                        dAesDecrypt.TransformFinalBlock(
                            daBuffer, 0, daBuffer.Length));
            }
        }
    }
}
```